# Is there a way to exclude files from a visual studio project template based on user input in Wizard?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, project-template

I am trying to create a project template in c# for visual studio.

Is there a way to include only certain files from the project template in the created project based on the input from wizard?

Example - the project template has class files - class1.cs , class2.cs, class3.cs
The user will be given an option to choose - 1 , 2 or 3 from the wizard while creating the project using the project template.

If the user chooses 1, only class1.cs should be added to the project created using the template. Class2.cs and Class3.cs should not be included in the project.

Comment: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 2):

Use `sources.modifiers` .The sources.modifiers allows you to include or exclude files from the solution based on a condition.

Here is the full [article](https://www.mytechramblings.com/posts/create-dotnet-templates-for-visual-studio-part-2/).

Comment: I have a problem with this. The files do get exclusing, but the new project solution/project still have a reference to the file in de .csproj file. So physically is gone, just not the reference yet. Got any tips?

Comment: @NielsLucas it has been a while but I will still try to explain. Not sure what type of file it is that you have a reference to it in your .csproj file but including/excluding files won't automatically add/remove reference to your .csproj file. You will have to conditionally include or exclude those references.